The problem of not receiving an alarm when there is an intersection in the indicator
Even though there is the intersection I want in the tradingview indicator(" ULUDAĞ SAR+LINEAR 2 ",overlay=true) indicator and the intersection text is written on the screen, the alarm is not activated. This may be due to the wrong criteria I chose or because the alarm is waiting not only for the intersection of the LRC lines but also for another criterion that I do not want, such as the lines touching the candles or the price.
I just want to be notified when the lrc lines intersect each other.
intersection is this;
if lrcShowLRC
if ta.crossover(lrcHighReg, lrcLowReg)
label.new(bar_index, low * 0.98, text="KESİŞME", color = color.orange, textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up, size = size.tiny)
I entered the length settings in the indicator as follows;
lrcLenHigh = input(400, title = "Uzunluk - High",  group = "LRC KESİŞME GİRDİLERİ")
lrcLenLow = input(314, title = "Uzunluk - Low", group = "LRC KESİŞME GİRDİLERİ")
On the 1-hour chart, there was an intersection on 21.09.2024 at 20:00. Intersection was written on the screen. that
wrote  indicating that there is an intersection in the shapes line.  But even though I tried changing all the criteria, the alarm did not work.
